# How to redirect from module path to root app path in Sinatra modular app?

Tags: ruby, module, sinatra

I have Sinatra base app like:

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    ..
  end
  get '/login' do
    ..
  end
end
```

and some sub modules like

```
class Protected < MyApp

  before '/*' do
    redirect('/login') unless logged_in
  end

  get '/list' do
    ...
  end
end
```

My config.ru is like below

```
map "/" do
  run MyApp
end

map "/protected" do
  run Protected
end
```

I'm getting redirect loop when trying to access `/protected/list` because it tries to redirect to **/protected/login** instead of **/login** from the main app. 
How can i force it to do right redirect? I know i can use `redirect to('../login')` but it seems bad.

Answer (score 2):

imo with Sinatra you only can assign URLs to constants then refer to them.

like:

```
MAIN_URL = '/'
PROTECTED_URL = '/protected'

class Protected < MyApp

before '/*' do
  redirect( MAIN_URL + 'login') unless logged_in
end

get '/list' do
  ...
end

map MAIN_URL do
  run MyApp
end

map PROTECTED_URL do
  run Protected
end
```

Ugly enough.

I would recommend to use [Espresso](http://e.github.com) instead.

It is very wise at routing as well as at another sides where other frameworks sucks.

The routing part is here: http://e.github.com/Routing.html

Answer (score 0):

From one of my apps in /config/application.rb

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base

  configure do

    APP_ROOT = Pathname.new(File.expand_path('../../', __FILE__))
    # By default, Sinatra assumes that the root is the file that
    # calls the configure block.
    # Since this is not the case for us, we set it manually.
    set :root, APP_ROOT.to_path
    ...
```

You could also define that constant in the config.ru like in first answer here.